# Changing "Pin It" button icon

Tags: android, android-layout, pinterest

How can I change my "Pin It" icon? Android:src on the xml file doesn't work.

```
<com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
    android:id="@+id/pin_bt"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/global_padding" />
```

Comment: try with background like **android:background="@drawable/pintrest"**

Comment: Is this authorized by Pinterest?

Comment: @kalyanpvs Background does not work to how I want it to be, changes the background of the "Pin It" image but pinit image is still in front.

Comment: @shkschneider i really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that you can change it using **setImageResource**.

Thank you guys.